# how to learn web service using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, service

im want to learn how to build a web service using vb.net.

unfortunately i couldn't find any websites that provides good tutorial..

can any one suggest a web site? thank u in advance ..

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at WCF, [this](http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/advanced/introduction-to-wcf-vb.aspx) seems like a fairly easy intro to that.